# Android Studio E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout error

Tags: android

Hi I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to find anything to help. My app used to work but has all of a sudden stopped and the only thing that has changed is that my phone(which I have been running the app on has updated)

This is my recycler view adapter class:

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<WeatherObject> dailyWeather;

protected Context context;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<WeatherObject> dailyWeather) {
    this.dailyWeather = dailyWeather;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerViewHolders viewHolder = null;
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.weather_daily_list, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {

    holder.dayOfWeek.setText(dailyWeather.get(position).getDayOfWeek());
    holder.weatherIcon.setImageResource(dailyWeather.get(position).getWeatherIcon());

    double mTemp = Double.parseDouble(dailyWeather.get(position).getWeatherResult());
    holder.weatherResult.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(mTemp)) + "°");

    holder.weatherResultSmall.setText(dailyWeather.get(position).getWeatherResultSmall());
    holder.weatherResultSmall.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dailyWeather.size();
}
```

}

This is my Recycler View Holder class:

public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

```
private static final String TAG = RecyclerViewHolders.class.getSimpleName();

public TextView dayOfWeek;

public ImageView weatherIcon;

public TextView weatherResult;

public TextView weatherResultSmall;

public RecyclerViewHolders(final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    dayOfWeek = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.day_of_week);
    weatherIcon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.weather_icon);
    weatherResult = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.weather_result);
    weatherResultSmall = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.weather_result_small);
}
```

}

And this is the weather activity class which sets the values:

public class WeatherActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

```
private static final String TAG = WeatherActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

private TextView cityCountry;

private TextView currentDate;

private ImageView weatherImage;

private String cardinalDirection;

private CircleView circleTitle;

private TextView windResult;

private TextView Direction;
```

//  private TextView sunRise;

```
private TextView humidityResult;

private RequestQueue queue;

private LocationMapObject locationMapObject;

private LocationManager locationManager;

private Location location;

private final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 200;

private CustomSharedPreference sharedPreference;

private String isLocationSaved;

private DatabaseQuery query;

private String apiUrl;

private FiveDaysForecast fiveDaysForecast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar != null){
        actionBar.hide();
    }

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    query = new DatabaseQuery(WeatherActivity.this);
    sharedPreference = new CustomSharedPreference(WeatherActivity.this);
    isLocationSaved = sharedPreference.getLocationInPreference();

    cityCountry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.city_country);
    currentDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_date);
    weatherImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.weather_icon);
    circleTitle = (CircleView)findViewById(R.id.weather_result);
    windResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wind_result);
    Direction  =   (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wind_direction);
    humidityResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.humidity_result);
   // sunRise =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sunrise_result);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WeatherActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
    } else {
        if(isLocationSaved.equals("")){
            // make API call with longitude and latitude
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 2, this);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                apiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+location.getLatitude()+"&lon="+location.getLongitude()+"&APPID="+Helper.API_KEY+"&units=metric";
                makeJsonObject(apiUrl);
            }
        }else{
            // make API call with city name
            String storedCityName = sharedPreference.getLocationInPreference();

            System.out.println("Stored city " + storedCityName);
            String[] city = storedCityName.split(",");
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(city[0])){
                System.out.println("Stored city " + city[0]);
                String url ="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city[0]+"&APPID="+Helper.API_KEY+"&units=metric";
                makeJsonObject(url);
            }
        }
    }

    ImageButton addLocation = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_location);
    addLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent addLocationIntent = new Intent(WeatherActivity.this, AddLocationActivity.class);
            startActivity(addLocationIntent);
        }
    });

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(WeatherActivity.this, 4);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.weather_daily_list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}


private void makeJsonObject(final String apiUrl){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, apiUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response " + response);
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = builder.create();
            locationMapObject = gson.fromJson(response, LocationMapObject.class);
            if (null == locationMapObject) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing was returned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response Good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String city = locationMapObject.getName() + ", " + locationMapObject.getSys().getCountry();
                String todayDate = getTodayDateInStringFormat();
                Long tempVal = Math.round(Math.floor(Double.parseDouble(locationMapObject.getMain().getTemp())));
                String weatherTemp = String.valueOf(tempVal) + "°";
                String weatherDescription = Helper.capitalizeFirstLetter(locationMapObject.getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                String windSpeed = locationMapObject.getWind().getSpeed();
                convertDegreeToCardinalDirection();
                String windDirection = cardinalDirection;
                String humidityValue = locationMapObject.getMain().getHumudity();
              //  String riseTime = locationMapObject.getSys().getSunrise();

                //save location in database
                if(apiUrl.contains("lat")){
                    query.insertNewLocation(locationMapObject.getName());
                }
                // populate View data
                cityCountry.setText(String.valueOf(city));
                currentDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(todayDate));
                circleTitle.setTitleText(Html.fromHtml(weatherTemp).toString());
                circleTitle.setSubtitleText(Html.fromHtml(weatherDescription).toString());
                windResult.setText(Html.fromHtml(windSpeed) + " km/h");
                Direction.setText(Html.fromHtml(windDirection) + " direction");
                humidityResult.setText(Html.fromHtml(humidityValue) + " %");
               // sunRise.setText(Html.fromHtml(riseTime));

                fiveDaysApiJsonObjectCall(locationMapObject.getName());
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //make api call
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 2, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    apiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+location.getLatitude()+"&lon="+location.getLongitude()+"&APPID="+Helper.API_KEY+"&units=metric";
                    makeJsonObject(apiUrl);
                }else{
                    apiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=51.5074&lon=0.1278&APPID="+Helper.API_KEY+"&units=metric";
                    makeJsonObject(apiUrl);
                }
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(WeatherActivity.this, getString(R.string.permission_notice), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    if (provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
    }
}

private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Goto Settings Page To Enable GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}

private String getTodayDateInStringFormat(){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMMM", Locale.getDefault());
    return df.format(c.getTime());
}

private void fiveDaysApiJsonObjectCall(String city){
    String apiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q="+city+ "&APPID="+Helper.API_KEY+"&units=metric";
    final List<WeatherObject> daysOfTheWeek = new ArrayList<WeatherObject>();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, apiUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response 5 days" + response);
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = builder.create();
            Forecast forecast = gson.fromJson(response, Forecast.class);
            if (null == forecast) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing was returned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response Good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                int[] everyday = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

                List<FiveWeathers> weatherInfo = forecast.getList();
                if(null != weatherInfo){
                    for(int i = 0; i < weatherInfo.size(); i++){
                        String time = weatherInfo.get(i).getDt_txt();
                        String shortDay = convertTimeToDay(time);
                        String temp = weatherInfo.get(i).getMain().getTemp();
                        String tempMin = weatherInfo.get(i).getMain().getTemp_min();

                        if(convertTimeToDay(time).equals("Mon") && everyday[0] < 1){
                            daysOfTheWeek.add(new WeatherObject(shortDay, R.drawable.small_weather_icon, temp, tempMin));
                            everyday[0] = 1;
                        }
                        if(convertTimeToDay(time).equals("Tue") && everyday[1] < 1){
                            daysOfTheWeek.add(new WeatherObject(shortDay, R.drawable.small_weather_icon, temp, tempMin));
                            everyday[1] = 1;
                        }
                        if(convertTimeToDay(time).equals("Wed") && everyday[2] < 1){
                            daysOfTheWeek.add(new WeatherObject(shortDay, R.drawable.small_weather_icon, temp, tempMin));
                            everyday[2] = 1;
                        }
                        if(convertTimeToDay(time).equals("Thu") && everyday[3] < 1){
                            daysOfTheWeek.add(new WeatherObject(shortDay, R.drawable.small_weather_icon, temp, tempMin));
                            everyday[3] = 1;
                        }
                        if(convertTimeToDay(time).equals("Fri") && everyday[4] < 1){
                            daysOfTheWeek.add(new WeatherObject(shortDay, R.drawable.small_weather_icon, temp, tempMin));
                            everyday[4] = 1;
                        }
                        if(convertTimeToDay(time).equals("Sat") && everyday[5] < 1){
                            daysOfTheWeek.add(new WeatherObject(shortDay, R.drawable.small_weather_icon, temp, tempMin));
                            everyday[5] = 1;
                        }
                        if(convertTimeToDay(time).equals("Sun") && everyday[6] < 1){
                            daysOfTheWeek.add(new WeatherObject(shortDay, R.drawable.small_weather_icon, temp, tempMin));
                            everyday[6] = 1;
                        }
                        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(WeatherActivity.this, daysOfTheWeek);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

private String convertTimeToDay(String time){
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SSSS", Locale.getDefault());
    String days = "";
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(time);
        System.out.println("Our time " + date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        days = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println("Our time " + days);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return days;
}
public void convertDegreeToCardinalDirection() {

    if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 348.75) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 360) ||
            (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 0) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 11.25)) {
        cardinalDirection = "N";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 11.25) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 33.75)) {
        cardinalDirection = "NNE";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 33.75) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 56.25)) {
        cardinalDirection = "NE";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 56.25) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 78.75)) {
        cardinalDirection = "ENE";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg()>= 78.75) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 101.25)) {
        cardinalDirection = "E";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 101.25) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg()<= 123.75)) {
        cardinalDirection = "ESE";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 123.75) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 146.25)) {
        cardinalDirection = "SE";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg()>= 146.25) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg()<= 168.75)) {
        cardinalDirection = "SSE";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 168.75) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 191.25)) {
        cardinalDirection = "S";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 191.25) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 213.75)) {
        cardinalDirection = "SSW";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 213.75) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 236.25)) {
        cardinalDirection = "SW";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 236.25) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 258.75)) {
        cardinalDirection = "WSW";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 258.75) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 281.25)) {
        cardinalDirection = "W";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 281.25) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 303.75)) {
        cardinalDirection = "WNW";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 303.75) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 326.25)) {
        cardinalDirection = "NW";
    } else if ((locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() >= 326.25) && (locationMapObject.getWind().getDeg() <= 348.75)) {
        cardinalDirection = "NNW";
    } else {
        cardinalDirection = "?";
    }
}

}
```

I know this is a lot to read but would someone be able to help point me in the right direction? Really confused considering it was working earlier today but now keep getting this error!

This is the weather object file:

public class WeatherObject {

```
private String dayOfWeek;

private int weatherIcon;

private String weatherResult;

private String weatherResultSmall;

public WeatherObject(String dayOfWeek, int weatherIcon, String weatherResult, String weatherResultSmall) {
    this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
    this.weatherIcon = weatherIcon;
    this.weatherResult = weatherResult;
    this.weatherResultSmall = weatherResultSmall;
}

public String getDayOfWeek() {
    return dayOfWeek;
}

public int getWeatherIcon() {
    return weatherIcon;
}

public String getWeatherResult() {
    return weatherResult;
}

public String getWeatherResultSmall() {
    return weatherResultSmall;
}
```

}

Comment: it's just a warning. attach an empty adapter to get rid of it - or just ignore it.

Comment: But none of the data now comes through?

Comment: you are obviously fetching it later on ...so you could first add an empty adapter and then replace it with a populated adapter. and it does not really matter, hence it is not an error... it's barely cosmetic, to reduce the logcat output by 1 line.

Comment: Okay and where should I add the empty adapter ? or does it matter?

Comment: right after having obtained an handle to the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: This is what I've added:        List<LocationMapObject> WeatherActivity = new ArrayList<LocationMapObject>();

                            // get a handle to the RecyclerView
                            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.weather_daily_list);
                            recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(WeatherActivity.this, daysOfTheWeek);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter); but I'm still getting the error, what am I missing?

Comment: why you call that `List<T>` `WeatherActivity`, does that make any sense ??

Comment: sorry that was wrong, for this particular one it is  final List<WeatherObject> daysOfTheWeek = new ArrayList<>(); then I get the JSON data and then this is added at the end        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.weather_daily_list);
                            recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(WeatherActivity.this, daysOfTheWeek);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter); so I have the empty adapter but I get the error still

Comment: I have edited my question to include the weather object class

Comment: So is anyone able to help me? Don't understand why someone has down voted this when I've tried researching this and as far I can tell I've coded it how it should be done. This worked earlier yesterday which is why I don't understand why it no longer works when I haven't changed the code at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue, it turns out it was a separate error that I found in the verbose part of the logcat, error was Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted. To fix this I added  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to my Android Manifest file